# JW Player with HTML5

Tags: html, flash, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I know this question has been asked many times here, but I could not come to a standard solution from them. So need help.

I simply need to show my .mp4 videos in jwplayer 5.10, such that it will show in flash version where it gets flash otherwise in html5 version.

Here's my code :

```
jwplayer("video_holder").setup({
    'height': '300',
    'width': '100%',
     modes: [
       { type: "flash",
         src: "player.swf",
         config: {
              file: "http://example.com/path/to/video.mp4",
         }
       },
       { type: "html5",
         config: {
              file: "http://example.com/path/to/video.mp4"
         }
       }
     ]
});
```

FYI : I am converting all my videos in .mp4 format, using ffmpeg, libx264
It does not load the video in Chrome and IOS, works with flash in FF.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can I see a link to where you are running this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it much more complicated than it really is. Here's a simple demo page that does what you want.

http://misterneutron.com/JW5video/

And here's the page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>JW5</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='myElement'>Loading the player...</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        flashplayer: 'player.swf',
        file: 'wildlife.mp4',
        image: 'wildlife.jpg',
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This configuration does play in all the desktop browsers, but not in IOS safari. It shows me:

"This video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported"

Is there a problem with my .mp4 file? As I said I am converting all other video file formats to .mp4 via ffmpeg service using the 
"libx264" codec. Is there any other specification about how to do it?

FYI: I tried with this video and it worked in my page too : http://misterneutron.com/JW5video/wildlife.mp4
So, it does seem like a problem with my file...

Comment: It certainly sounds like an encoding problem. Run your video through HandBrake, default options plus check "Web optimized," and see if that fixes it: http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: Yes, it IS an encoding problem, that's for sure. However, is there some guide about the audio/video codecs that this player can play for an mp4 file?

Comment: This is the only info they provide: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference. But it's not JW Player that's really the issue, here. On iOS, it just passes the video to the device browser's native <video> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it plays fine with the jwplayer configuration made by MisterNeutron. It seems the problem was for some reason, the player was not able to access the videos in my local machine (may be some problem with permission, will investigate later). However it played fine in my DEV server.

In case someone stumbles upon this post and want a better explanation:

I am converting all user uploaded videos to mp4 extension to be played by jwplayer in flash version and html5 video on fallback. The  ffmpeg video conversion script is like follows:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 'input_file' -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -strict experimental 'output_file'
```

Hope this helps somebody and thanks a lot for your help.